# How to split array based on the element in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two array: array1 and array2. So array1 will be splitted based on the element insided array2. For example:

```
array1["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
array2["2","5"]
```

My code:

```
var prev = 0;
newArray = []; 
for (var ii in array2) {
    var index = array1.indexOf(array2[ii]);

    if (index != prev) {
        newArray.push(array1.slice(prev, index));
        prev = index;
    }
 }
 newArray.push(array1.slice(prev));
```

The result will be :

```
["1"],["2","3","4"],["5","6"]
```

But now i facing the problem of array1's element can be not in order. For example:`["1","5","3","4","2","6"]`. So based on the code i have, it will split the array1 wrongly because first element in array2 is "2", so it already split the array1 into two `["1","5","3","4"],["2","6"]`. And next when come to "5", it cannot find it.

The expected result is:`["1"],["5","3","4"],["2","6"]`

So how to split array1 based on array2 no matter array1 in ascending ,descending or random order. Sorry my english is not good. Hope you guys can understand.

Comment: Are the values in `array2` `unique`?

Comment: @ArmanCharan Yes..

Comment: If there are multiple `"2"s` in `array1`: should they all be split points? Or just the first occurrence?

Comment: @ArmanCharan the values inside array1 also unique

Comment: Without it being in sorted order, the time complexity will grow substantially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It loops through `array1` and pushes each item into a temporary array. When the item is found in `array2` the temporary array is pushed into the final array and then reset.

```js
var array1 = ["1", "5", "3", "4", "2", "6"];
var array2 = ["2", "5"];

var newArray = [];
var currArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

  // Item exists in array2. Add to newArray and reset currArray
  if (i > 0 && array2.includes(array1[i])) {
    newArray.push(currArray);
    currArray = [];
  }

  currArray.push(array1[i]);
}

newArray.push(currArray); // Add final currArray to newArray

console.log(newArray); // print result
```

On a side note, it's best not to use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate through an array if index order is important (as in your case) as it does not return the indexes in any particular order. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment would be nice to know what could be improved.

Comment: I did not downvote this, but note that your answer is O(M*N), while the answer by @Arman Charan is only O(M).

Comment: That's what's frustrating about SO.  A downvote without anything to suggest there is something wrong with the answer, the explanation, or any idea on what to improve.

Comment: im not good with arrays I just want to know how you come up with `O(M*N)` ? @Phrogz

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz. If there's `Array.reduce` and `Set.has` does it still count as O(M) though?

Comment: Yes. The `O(M*N) complexity` is a result of using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) within a [`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: @ArmanCharan does calling `Set.has` within `Array.reduce` not have the same complexity?

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes()` executes a blind search every time it is called. `Set.has()` retrieves `values` using organised `keys` [at `sublinear` pace](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-set-objects). See the following for more info: [`Time Complexity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). [Actual `Array.includes()` vs `Set.has()` benchmark](https://jsperf.com/array-includes-and-find-methods-vs-set-has) @H77 ✌️

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain @ArmanCharan. Something is definitely slowing your solution down though: https://jsperf.com/49604479. Maybe the results would be different for a larger array. Or maybe it's `Array.reduce` vs a for loop.

Comment: [`Array.reduce()` is significantly slower than `for`](https://jsperf.com/array-reduce-vs-for-loop/3). I imagine the setup time of `Set` and small `input` don't help either. Everything's a tradeoff, I guess 

Answer (score 9):

See [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for more info.

```js
// Split Up.
const splitup = (array, keys) => (set => array.reduce((output, value) => {
  if (set.has(value)) output.push([value]) // Split.
  else output[output.length-1].push(value) // Append.
  return output
}, [[]]))(new Set(keys))

// Output.
const output1 = splitup(["1","2","3","4","5","6"], ["2","5"])
console.log(...output1) // ["1"],["2","3","4"],["5","6"]
const output2 = splitup(["1","5","3","4","2","6"], ["2","5"])
console.log(...output2) // ["1"],["5","3","4"],["2","6"]
```

Comment: My preferred answer if the code (primarily arrow functions) was less concise and more readable.  Still +1.  Like the way it reads `if (set.has(value))` ..  you can't make JavaScript anymore like pseudo-code than that.  Well done